# Can't download dalle generated image on onClick

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, openai-api

Hello I am trying to make a button download an image generated by DALLE, but when I click the button it gives me this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at`  Here is my page code :

```
"use client";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Download, Image } from "lucide-react";
import Heading from "@/components/heading";
import { amountOptions, formSchema, resolutionOptions } from "./constants";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import OpenAI from "openai";
import { Empty } from "@/components/empty";
import { Loader } from "@/components/loader";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { Card, CardFooter } from "@/components/ui/card";
import downloadPhoto from "./downolad";
import appendNewToName from "./newname";
const ImagePage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      prompt: "",
      amount: "1",
      resolution: "512x512",
    },
  });

  const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      setImages([]);
      const response = await axios.post("/api/image", values);

      const urls = response.data.map((image: { url: string }) => image.url);
      setImages(urls);
      form.reset();
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      router.refresh();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Heading
        title="Image"
        description="Generate Images with AI"
        icon={Image}
        iconColor="text-pink-700"
      />
      <div className="px-4 lg:px-8">
        <div>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="rouned-lg border w-full p-4 px-3 md:px-6 focus-within:shadow-sm grid grid-cols-12 gap-2"
            >
              <FormField
                name="prompt"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-6">
                    <FormControl className="m-0 p-0">
                      <Input
                        className="border-0 outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent"
                        disabled={isLoading}
                        placeholder="Samurai riding a horse in the forest."
                        {...field}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="amount"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2">
                    <Select
                      disabled={isLoading}
                      onValueChange={field.onChange}
                      value={field.value}
                      defaultValue={field.value}
                    >
                      <FormControl>
                        <SelectTrigger>
                          <SelectValue defaultValue={field.value} />
                        </SelectTrigger>
                      </FormControl>
                      <SelectContent>
                        {amountOptions.map((amount) => (
                          <SelectItem key={amount.value} value={amount.value}>
                            {amount.label}
                          </SelectItem>
                        ))}
                      </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="resolution"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2">
                    <Select
                      disabled={isLoading}
                      onValueChange={field.onChange}
                      value={field.value}
                      defaultValue={field.value}
                    >
                      <FormControl>
                        <SelectTrigger>
                          <SelectValue defaultValue={field.value} />
                        </SelectTrigger>
                      </FormControl>
                      <SelectContent>
                        {resolutionOptions.map((resolution) => (
                          <SelectItem
                            key={resolution.value}
                            value={resolution.value}
                          >
                            {resolution.label}
                          </SelectItem>
                        ))}
                      </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />

              <Button
                className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full"
                disabled={isLoading}
              >
                Generate
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <div className="space-y-4 mt-4">
          {isLoading && (
            <div className="p-20">
              <Loader />
            </div>
          )}

          {images.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
            <Empty label="No images generated" />
          )}
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-5 mt-8">
            {images.map((src) => (
              <Card key={src} className="rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
                <div className="relative aspect-square">
                  <img alt="image" src={src} width={500} height={500} />
                </div>
                <CardFooter className="p-2">
                  <Button
                    variant="secondary"
                    className="w-full"
                    onClick={() => downloadPhoto(src, appendNewToName(src))}
                  >
                    <Download className="h-4 w-4 mr-4" />
                  </Button>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImagePage;
```

Here is my download.ts file function:

```
function forceDownload(blobUrl: string, filename: string) {
    let a: any = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = filename;
    a.href = blobUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
  }
  
  export default function downloadPhoto(url: string, filename: string) {
    fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        Origin: location.origin,
      }),
      mode: "cors",
    })
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        forceDownload(blobUrl, filename);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
    }
```

and my newname.ts file function :

```
export default function appendNewToName(name: string) {
    let insertPos = name.indexOf(".");
    let newName = name
      .substring(0, insertPos)
      .concat("-new", name.substring(insertPos));
    return newName;
  }
```

The functions work on replicate.com models but not on dalle.I tried changing the function but it doesn't work so changed it back